# using Json In WPF C#

Tags: c#, json

I am new in Json and I install the Newton package
 and I try to Deserialze Data
I create a Class name users. and added the properties.

however when I try to return the deserialaztion it return null.

here is the json: [{"Id":"0","userPhone":"000000000","userName":"Barak","Conferance_ID":"1"}]

and here is my code:

```
public class Users
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string userPhone { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string Conferance_ID { get; set; }

} 


    /// <summary>
    /// when user clicked on btn Enter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the button btnEnter Clicked</param>
    /// <param name="e">the event argument of button clicked</param>
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "mywebsite.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string str_Json =  reader.ReadToEnd();


                List<Users> LUsers  = Json.JsonParser.Deserialize<List<Users>>(str_Json);                                       
            }



        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Newtownsoft?  If so: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users[]>(str_Json);`

Comment: Unrelated to your serialization problem, but do not try to do your web requests synchronously in the click handler. Since the click handler will be executed in the UI thread, the GUI will freeze until the web request+response have been processed, which - depending on server and network environment - could take some time. Rather do it asynchronously (keywords: async, await)

Comment: Did you try to use **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>** instead of **Json.JsonParser.Deserialize<List<Users>>**?

Comment: @maccettura I've never had trouble with deserializing to a `List<T>` with Json.net.

Comment: If you are using [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), be aware that the documentation specifically says to use Newtonsoft's Json.net.

Comment: And if you need documentation: [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Comment: If you actually use Json.NET by doing `List<Users> LUsers  = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(str_Json);` then it works perfectly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HDidSR.   What is `Json.JsonParser.Deserialize`?

Comment: Thanks Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(s‌​tr_Json); works Great